# Is there any way to modify endpoints on ClientConfig on a Silverlight App?

Tags: c#, silverlight, config

I have managed to read key-value vars from web.config to my silverlight app and now I want on the method "Application_Startup" (for saying something) to modify the Endpoint Address with some of the values I got.

I have tried to use System.Configuration to open it (but it doesn't exist on silverlight), thought about scripts but anything seems to work or be feasible (scripts to modify it after build, but the app is allready ziped at that time).
Don't try to understand why im doing this cause is maintanance duty and saddly must be done :(.

Thanks in advise

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming `WS` is an instance of your data service client and `ServerAddress` is the IP or DNS for your server, you can do something like this:

```
WS.Endpoint.Address = New System.ServiceModel.EndpointAddress(ServerAddress)
```

Comment: Sorry, this is VB but I am sure you can convert this 1 line to C#

Comment: thanks steve, it was something like that. I needed to config the binding and set it togheter with the endpoint i got from web.config to my proxy object on silverlight side